# Ajax подгрузка мобильного меню (hc-offcanvas-nav)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Всех приветствую! Как сделать Ajax подгрузку, чтобы при клике по кнопке, меню загружалось, а не загружалось при загрузке сайта? Код добавил на codepen, для отображения меню измените ширину экрана. Заранее спасибо, отвечаю быстро :)

https://codepen.io/foreigndezigner/pen/XWJMyMK

```
<div class="error">Код больше 30000 символов, поэтому невозможно вставить на сайте</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let trigM = false;

$("body").on("click", "#menu", function() {
  if (!trigM) {
  
    trigM = true;
    let menuWrapper = document.createElement('div');
    let menuUl = document.createElement('ul');

    menuWrapper.classList.add('menu_mobile');

    document.body.appendChild(menuWrapper);
    menuWrapper.appendChild(menuUl)

    var arrayLinksText = ['menu link 1', 'menu link 2', 'menu link 3', 'menu link 4'];
    var arrayLinks = ['http://somelink-1', 'http://somelink-2', 'http://somelink-3', 'http://somelink-4']

    for (let i = 0; i < arrayLinksText.length; i++) {
      let menuLi = document.createElement('li');
      let menuA = document.createElement('a');
      menuA.setAttribute('href', arrayLinks[0 + 1]);
      menuUl.appendChild(menuLi);
      menuLi.appendChild(menuA);
      menuA.innerHTML = arrayLinksText[0 + i];
    }
    
  } else {
  
    trigM = false;
    document.querySelector('.menu_mobile').remove()
    //menuWrapper.remove(); 
    
  }
});
```

```css
.menu_mobile {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 10;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 15px;
}

.menu_mobile ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.menu_mobile ul li {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu" id="menu">MENU</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
$('#mobMenuBtn').click(function() {
  $('#mobileNav').show();
});
```

```html
<header>
  <button id="mobMenuBtn">Кнопка Меню</button>
</header>

<nav id="mobileNav" hidden>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/" style="text-transform: uppercase;"><strong>Главная</strong></a></li>
    <li><a href="/about" style="text-transform: uppercase;"><strong>О нас</strong></a></li>
    <li><a href="/contact" style="text-transform: uppercase;"><strong>Контакты</strong></a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Вопрос звучит: `чтобы при клике по кнопке, меню загружалось, а не загружалось при загрузке сайта`, но в вашем примере оно присутствует изначально.